# whether the packet is delivered by router or the sender if sniffing is used?

Tags: wireshark, packet-sniffers, rssi

guys,

I am recently trying to capture the RSSI value in the packet which is broadcasted by the cellphone and received by the laptop in monitor mode. (Instead of directly connecting the cell phone to the desktop or connect the laptop to the cell phone, both the cell phone and the laptop are connected to the same wifi in my home.)

With Wireshark, I had successfully grasped the packets which are sent from the cellphone and received by the laptop. And I can find the Signal Strength in each packet. However, when I read the content of the packet, it is said that the packet is transmitted by the router.

So my question is whether the packet is delivered by the router or the sender when we use Wireshark to make the laptop enter monitor mode? Will the Signal Strength reflect the signal strength between the router and the laptop or the strength between the cell phone and the laptop?

The following paragraph is part of the content of one packet I sniffed, the sender address, transmitter address, and the receiver address are listed in this pic:
[packet information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDxj8.jpg)

Can anyone give any suggestions? I will appreciate it a lot.